# How to get alert notifications to function with Phonegap 1.1.0 and iOS5

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, cordova

I am upgrading a Phonegap App to Phonegap 1.1.0 (from 9.4) and building with the new iOS5 SDK and Xcode 4.2.

The same happens when trying PhoneGap 1.0.0 as well.

The app has an about button that launches a notification dialog, but it is not firing after upgrading.

Here is the HTML from the Phonegap App

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.1.1.0.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        function onDeviceReady(){
            //do something
        }

function OnPageLoad(){

      document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

}

        function alertDismissed() {
            // do something
        }


function onAlertBtn()
    {
    navigator.notification.alert("Test Alert Message", alertDismissed, "Test Alert", "Done"); 

    }

</script>

</head>

<body onload="OnPageLoad()">

<div align="center">
  <FORM>
<INPUT type="button" style="font-size: 18px;" value="About"  onClick="onAlertBtn();" >
</FORM> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after considerable trial and error, a fix has been found!

Modify the source to be...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        function onDeviceReady(){
            //do something
        }

function OnPageLoad(){

      document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

}

        function alertDismissed() {
            // do something
        }


function onAlertBtn()
    {
    navigator.notification.alert("Test Alert Message", alertDismissed, "Test Alert", "Done"); 

    }

</script>

</head>

<body onload="OnPageLoad()">

<div align="center">
  <FORM>
<INPUT type="button" style="font-size: 18px;" value="About"  onClick="onAlertBtn();" >
</FORM> </div>

</body>
</html>
```